# Azure website not connecting to the Azure SQL database through main login

Tags: asp.net, azure-sql-database

I am not able to access the azure sql database when deployed the azurewebsite, i.e 'urlname@azurewebsites.net', where as I can whilst on my machine, even though I am using the same connection string to connect to the database, it connects and works fire until I publish it and the access is denied for the user, I traced the error.
Even through the user is dbo and thats the main login for the database.

Error:
Login failed for user 'dbUser'

Connection string:

```
connectionString="Server=tcp:ic0tzk59fi.database.windows.net,1433;Database=ews-system_db;User ID=dbUser@ic0tzk59fi;Password=DB@user87;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;"
```

I have tried to search for the problem but couldn't find any where, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to allow your azure website to access azure sql. When you have configured azure SQL, you might have added your local IP to azure sql as firewall exception list - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee621782.aspx - refer this link for more info.

You might need to proceed with the website in similar manner.

Comment: I already have that option allowed for windows azure services, to have them access the azure severs which host the database, but that doesn't solve the problem, that was the first thing I checked.

Comment: Make sure you have website and DB server in same region.